# Python Pandas read_excel different behavior in parsing MultiIndex dataframe between Pandas 0.18.1 and Pandas > 0.19

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am totally confused. Probably I miss an update in `pandas` API.

So I have this `excel` file

[image]

In `Pandas 0.18.1` I did not encounter any issue in reading and parsing the file. I used the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
fname = 'SAMPLE_EXCEL_CAUSING_ERROR_IN_PANDAS_0_19_UP.xlsx'
pd.read_excel(fname, 'Sheet1', header=[0,1], index=[0,1])
```

It returned something that I wish for.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muliy.png]

Recently, I updated my packages, and now my `pandas` is in `version 0.20.1`. However, when I tried to execute the same code with the same excel file, it returned an error. Here is the error message: `ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2`.

[image]

Any clue where did I miss the new API in `read_excel`? I am totally confused. Is there any workaround to read the `excel` file with `MultiIndex` columns? My real data has level 3 index instead of level 2 index. Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

P.S. I cannot downgrade into `0.18.1` because my users are using `0.20.1`

**UPDATE**

Strangely if I set the `header` into `header=[1,2]` then it did not throw any error message. However, I got the wrong level as my Index. Still trying to get the workaround for this issue.

[image]

Comment: iirc there was a change as to how pandas read/wrote (it didn't in one version) multi-indexes - it's probably in the version change logs?

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the clue. Still struggling googling and find out how to properly use the `header` and `index` in `read_excel` for `pandas version 0.19` or higher.

Comment: Hmmm, do you need `pd.read_excel(fname, 'Sheet1', header=[0,1], index=0)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Tried to change the `index=[0,1]` to `index=0` as per your suggestion, but it still throws me the same error. `ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I had the same error in version 0.23.1, but in 0.24.1, it tells me `ValueError: cannot specify usecols when specifying a multi-index header` (I indeed tried multiindex header + usecols).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make your index semi-manually

## Get the header

Only take the first 2 rows, starting from the second column, and fill the empty cells starting from the left

```
header = pd.read_excel(fname, 'Sheet1', index=[0], header=None).iloc[:2, 1:].ffill(axis=1)
```

## Get the data

omit the first 2 rows, and set the first column as index

```
df = pd.read_excel(fname, 'Sheet1', skiprows=[0,1], index=0, header=None).rename(columns={0: 'A'}).set_index('A')
```

## `MultiIndex`

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(header.values)
```

> df

```
    B       D       F
    C   C   E   E   G   G
A                       
A1  X   Y   Z   U   J   K
A2  XX  YY  ZZ  UU  JJ  KK
A3  XXX     YYY     ZZZ     UUU     JJJ     KKK
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Finally found the workaround for my problem!

Comment: Annoying to have to workaround this, but pretty good solution. I would put the parameter `nrows=2` in `read_excel` while reading the header. Otherwise you actually parse the full sheet twice.

Answer (score 0):

I use anaconda on windows and I did an update on pandas using:

```
conda update pandas
```

and now i get the desired result.

here's my data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho13H.png

and this the result:

```
  pandas.read_excel(file, index_col=0, header=[0,1])
Out[7]: 
            MIN                                                            \
             C1       C2           C3       C4       T1       T2       T3   
0    195.207890        -   101.464978  142.434        -        -  943.799   
1   1018.091967  982.585  1008.165221   1089.3  3579.36  2897.13        -   
3    719.242505  768.078   798.991606  979.055   1562.6  1503.61  1635.22   
7    464.714785  115.527   339.229797  68.8829  181.388  552.229   809.36   
8    238.469139  173.027   197.930122        -  633.154  610.908  495.791   
10   384.770673  532.663   230.583377  444.087  2105.43  1109.59  1362.43   
14   420.279847  401.482   323.935379  393.111  1135.14  969.754  1030.53   
15   529.268355  375.933   501.639846  561.166  3001.63   3030.6  2617.78   
21   262.806700  259.203   444.979777        -  1194.33  1260.72  1070.19   
28   280.283310  287.044   275.809979  257.798  622.784  899.187  512.905   

                         COM                ...                               \
             T4           C1           C2   ...              T3           T4   
0   1235.989828   132.088723   127.384065   ...     1647.217230   448.336279   
1   3406.803144  1092.341474  1263.549755   ...     3399.548560  3144.652639   
3   1400.570267   911.110083   754.166616   ...     1651.774770  1690.612134   
7    734.734422   587.381973   568.188789   ...      872.138431   912.248578   
8    417.361810   182.506544   164.936057   ...      765.018292  1070.565315   
10  1148.614845   424.377037   449.054287   ...     1293.657158  1960.196871   
14   947.046046   536.630139   482.741047   ...     1041.749363  1159.747331   
15  2164.517695   558.597139   721.841033   ...     2548.803301  2743.534159   
21  1198.080826   530.759489   663.639841   ...     1372.536515  1296.604595   
28   665.474002   453.753921   236.935726   ...     1001.108816   677.224724   

           UND                                                              \
            C1          C2          C3       C4       T1       T2       T3   
0    17.126508   86.103158   84.637729        -        -    438.8  2004.51   
1   856.588602  696.177886  697.322434  684.055  4238.82  3420.76  2339.89   
3   523.836538  488.007532  804.293445  467.541        -  666.135  594.047   
7   289.235298  272.521236  239.166506  250.247  602.523  449.244  547.401   
8   140.495332   77.390391  114.810278  149.386        -        -        -   
10  220.994094  208.610597  233.131489  223.641  1082.33  1115.45  1040.81   
14  228.683350  250.932989  213.735624  225.627  623.491  598.308  555.539   
15  283.552101  280.930293  293.570089  244.061  791.533  1181.63  1069.91   
21  243.737751  233.957191  200.573198  203.905  795.793  903.329  1029.72   
28  155.424805  236.211838  197.738949  175.754  728.167  687.443  917.051   


         T4  
0   1555.74  
1   3369.02  
3   679.208  
7   207.939  
8         -  
10  1043.51  
14  602.447  
15  844.655  
21  958.073  
28  572.275  

[10 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: What is your Pandas version number?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem comes from duplicated column names, e.g., two (B, C) columns in the example.